Google Sheets: Count how many there are per month, year and status
This is the table:



decision
date




decline
2024-07-31 17:55:35


remindmelater
2024-07-01 17:38:26


purchase
2024-07-31 20:18:10


purchase
2023-05-25 22:34:17


purchase
2023-05-12 16:46:21


decline
2022-05-12 20:09:16


purchase
2022-05-24 16:31:53


purchase
2022-05-29 18:19:56



I would like to have something like:



Year
Month
Total
Purchased
decline or remindmelater




2024
7
3
1
2


2023
5
1
1
0


2023
6
1
1
0


2022
5
3
2
1



But if I use this formula. It displays the number 1
=COUNTIFS(YEAR($B$2:$B$1679), F5, MONTH($B$2:$B$1679), E5)

If I use this formula to get all the purchased, it displays error "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size."
=COUNTIFS(YEAR($B$2:$B$1679), F5, MONTH($B$2:$B$1679), E5, $A$2:$A$1679, "purchase")

This is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MdkQtOAe03WCTrCZaR66XKD2xICJDNEFYsyc_RDUC_g/edit?usp=sharing

Using the sample data table  given in the beginning of the first message, I Have used 3 formulas to create the result table.
Assuming the data is in range A1:B9, first formula to be entered in cell D1 is:
=query(A2:B,"Select Year(B), Month(B)+1, Count(A) Where Year(B) Is Not Null Group By Year(B), Month(B)+1 Label Year(B) 'YEAR', Month(B)+1 'MONTH', Count(A) 'TOTAL'")

The formula in cell G1 is:
=arrayformula({"PURCHASED";if(D2:D="","",countifs(year(B2:B),D2:D,month(B2:B),E2:E,A2:A,"purchase"))})
The formula in cell H1 is:
=arrayformula({"DECLINED";if(D2:D="","",countifs(year(B2:B),D2:D,month(B2:B),E2:E,A2:A,"decline"))})
And, the formula in cell I1 is:
=arrayformula({"REMINDME/BILLME LATER";if(D2:D="","",countifs(year(B2:B),D2:D,month(B2:B),E2:E,A2:A,"<>decline",A2:A,"<>purchase"))})
.

.
EDIT:
Another alternative is, to use the single formula below in cell D1 and the whole table will be populated as seen in the image below;
=ARRAYFORMULA(
QUERY(
{A2:B,IF(A2:A="decline",A2:A,""),IF(A2:A="purchase",A2:A,""), IF(A2:A="remindmelater",A2:A,""), IF(A2:A="billmelater",A2:A,""), IF(A2:A="renewal",A2:A,"")},
"Select Year(Col2), Month(Col2)+1, Count(Col3), Count(Col4), (Count(Col5)+Count(Col6)), Count(Col7), Count(Col1) 
Where Col1 Is Not Null 
Group By Year(Col2), Month(Col2) 
Label Year(Col2) 'YEAR', Month(Col2)+1 'MONTH', Count(Col3) 'DECLINE', Count(Col4) 'PURCHASE', (Count(Col5)+Count(Col6)) 'REMINDME/BILLME_LATER', Count(Col7) 'RENEWAL', Count(Col1) 'TOTAL'"
))

.

You can see the two alternatives in the sample sheet from the link below;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeZfkgC8QCmA8rLRMNFE8xxlXRg4iAjzYb3kS54nxCQ/edit?usp=sharing
.

You should use the ARRAYFORMULA function.
Functions like YEAR(B2:B1679) or MONTH(B2:B1679) generate arrays of values. You can try entering a simple example like YEAR(B2:B5) and see that an error is generated in this case.
For your specific use case you can fix the formula with something like this
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(YEAR(B2:B1679), F5, MONTH(B2:B1679), E5, A2:A1679, "purchase"))

